# какая библиотека у strncpy в win32api?

Tags: winapi, ассемблер, fasm, msdn

в документации нет об этом не слова вроде. в линуксе это было в libc наверное или в libstdc. я пишу на ассемблере и мне нужно знать имя dll, чтобы экспортировать функцию.

Comment: Это функция из рантайма С. msvcrt.dll если использовать vc++

Comment: К winapi эта функция не имеет ни малейшего отношения.

Comment: @user7860670, даже если не использовать vc++ ничего не мешает использовать эту функцию.

Comment: @insolor да, потому что один фиг все библиотеки на ассемблере получаются. какой бы не был язык.

Comment: @xverizex, не на ассемблере, а в машинном коде.